# TV doesn't work as single monitor for PC

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, dvi, external-display, tv

Hello i am running Debian Jessie with KDE and i am trying to use my Sony Bravia TV as a monitor but i have a very curious problem. The TV has a VGA cable which i connect to the computer via a DVI adapter because that's the only available type of port. The graphics card has 2 DVI ports.

When i connect the TV to the computer as dual monitor (with another normal computer monitor) it works fine. If i plug out the DVI cable of the other monitor the TV keeps working fine.

If i shut down and remove the other monitor's DVI cable the TV works fine until KDE starts loading (after i enter the login user & password). Then it shows the hard disk loading and at that moment the TV (single monitor at this point) goes black and gives me a msg of "no signal". At this moment, if i plug back in the other monitor the TV starts working again normally. The other monitor doesn't even need to be turned on or being plugged into power for this to work, just needs the DVI cable connected to it.

So basically this TV works fine but only if i use it with another monitor. On its own, it doesn't work pas the KDM loading screen! I tried switching ports and trying different orders of turning it on and plugging stuff in and all kinds of things but it's always the same result.

I am using the free ATI driver that comes with Debian.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. This is a Q&A site, not a forum. Please do not update your post with the solution. It is acceptable for you to answer your own question. Please do so by clicking the "Post Your Answer" button below.

Comment: i'm sorry i could not find the button

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by unchecking system settings > startup and shutdown > service manager > kscreen2